# InvalidOperationException when jumping with windows phone LongListSelector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector, invalidoperationexception

I have already made some view with a LongListSelector, but now I have a really strange issue...
In fact, when I try to "tap" on my GroupHeader to my JumpList, my application throw an InvalidOperationException.

My container Model:

```
    public class NextArrivalContainer<T> : List<T>
{
    #region Properties

    public string   Destination     { get; private set; }
    public string   Line            { get; private set; }

    #endregion //Properties

    public NextArrivalContainer(string key, List<T> items)
        : base(items)
    {
        if (key.Contains(' '))
        {
            int index   = key.IndexOf(' ');
            Line        = key.Substring(0, index);
            Destination = key.Substring(index + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            Destination = string.Empty;
            Line        = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel Property:

```
        private List<Model.NextArrivalContainer<string>>    _trams;
    public List<Model.NextArrivalContainer<string>>     Trams
    {
        get { return (_trams); }
        set
        {
            if (_trams != value)
            {
                _trams = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Trams");
            }
        }
    }
```

My ViewModel where I fill the Property:

```
            var tramGrouped = from item in trams
                          orderby item.Destination
                          group item by item.Destination into tramGroupedByDestination
                          select new Model.NextArrivalContainer<string>(tramGroupedByDestination.Key,
                              (from item in tramGroupedByDestination select item.Time).ToList());

        Trams = new List<Model.NextArrivalContainer<string>>(tramGrouped);
```

And my View:

```
            <phone:PivotItem Header="Tram">
            <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Trams}"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
                                    GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource TramHeaderTemplate}"
                                    JumpListStyle="{StaticResource JumpStyle}"
                                    IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                                    HideEmptyGroups="True"
                                    LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="70, 50"/>
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

And his template:

```
    <Style TargetType="phone:LongListSelector" x:Key="JumpStyle">
        <Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="List"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource backgroundConverter}}"
                            Width="450" Height="70">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Destination}"
                                   Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource foregroundConverter}}"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I am looking forward your answers.

Edit:

I just try something, my view was a UserControl, (I didn't know why I did it, but I did...)
So I try to changes to a phone:PhoneApplicationPage and It fix my issue.

If somebody can explain me why.
I hope that my question will help another developers.